# Stream video from protected directory in Android app

Tags: java, android, .htaccess, video-streaming

I have a problem while I am streaming video file in my Android app from protected directory on server. I am using basic HTTP authentication (htaccess).

I am sending username and password in URL and then parse it into URI but it's not working. I have an Apache server on which I have created a directory and uploaded a video file in it and protected that directory with `.htaccess`.

When I stream video without .`htaccess` protection it streams fine but when I do it with protected directory it does not stream video and gives an error:

> Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: werplay.com/LT_Data/LTWalkthroughVideos/test.mp4";

I have given the code snippet below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    String LINK = "http://user:pass@www.site.com/Folder1/Folder2/test.mp4";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        playServerVideo(false,LINK);

    }
    public  void playServerVideo(boolean controls, String url)
    {

        Uri video = Uri.parse(url);



        if (controls)
        {
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
            videoView.start();
        }
        else
        {
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
           // videoView.
            videoView.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested the server with curl on a standard PC? "not working" is not a very descriptive explanation of a failure state, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you need more to understand the problem, I guess I have tried to describe the problem as much as I can, I have a apache server on which I have created a directory and uploaded a video file in it and protected that directory with .htaccess and now I am trying to stream that video in my android app and code is given above.

Comment: and the problem that I am getting is when I stream video without .htaccess protection it streams fine but when I do it with protected directory it doesnot stream video and gives an error 
" Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.werplay.com/LT_Data/LTWalkthroughVideos/test.mp4"

Comment: @halfer did you understand the problem? its been three days I am stuck on it and second time posting this question.

Comment: Much better! I don't understand why this was not in the question originally, but that is much more answerable now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution to this problem, this error was occurring because I was running the app on emulator, when test the same thing on device it worked perfectly fine.